# Как исключить содержимое папки resources в build проекта?

Tags: java

В поем проекте есть папка resources, как исключить её содержимое в артефактах при построении проекта ?

Comment: Встречный вопрос: а как вы собираете?

Comment: В артифактах делаю build.

Comment: где в вопросе вы показали как вы это артефакт создавали и что указали в его содержимом?

Comment: хотите, чтобы в билд попадало только то, что вы хотите - укажите в билде, что должно попадать в него и собирайте

Comment: плюс, я крайне сомневаюсь в верности вашего выбора способа сборки. С большой долей вероятности вы работаете либо с maven, либо с gradle, но почему-то все равно выбираете в качестве системы сборки артефакты идеи

Comment: В артефакт вы скорее всего добавляете `module output`. И папка ресурсов модуля входит в сборку данного модуля. Перейдите в настройки модуля и исключите эту папку (хотя я не понимаю зачем вам это нужно)